# External page div load with jQuery element error

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery

If anybody that knows jQuery better than me (probably 99% here since this is my first week trying this code :) have some time left over here´s a question that I really need some answer to. Sorry for some incorrect english.

Some of you have probably read the other questions I asked about putting external page content into divs and UI select-slide elements that dosent load properly in such loaded divs, this is a continuation on that subject and now I hope to solve this and I make a new subject to gather the info here. The main question is Why UI-sliders (select elements) dont work when they are loaded (from div in another page) to divs via jQuery (in same homepage).

This is the code I am using to load content into the site:

```
load_script.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div_that_will_receive_content').load('from_page.html #from_div');
});
```

**Problem:** The problem occurs in two different ways.
1: When only the DIV is loaded the slider dosent show, evrything els in the div shows and the div loads correct except from the slider. The slider shows up for 0.1 second at the loading moment then disapears.
2: When a entire site is loaded in (included ui sliders) the content loops and the site never stops loading, when checking in browser consol 25-30mb is loaded in seconds. Even in this case the slider shows for maybe 0.1 second exacly at load moment, and becuse the of the loop-loading of the site the slider flashes.

#### Page_1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="load_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div_1">DIV 1 = This is where the content of div_2 should be</div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Page_2.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="load_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
});
</script>
 </head>
<body>

<div id="div_2">DIV 2 = This div containing a slide-select-element will be loaded to to     div_1</div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### load_script.js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div_1').load('Page_2 #div_2');
});
</script>
```

---

I am still having some problems with this. Now the problem is that if I load the entire Page2.html into the div in Page1.html it all goes well. But if I just load in selected divs from Page2.html the slide-elements dont show up, but the rest of the content does (text).

This work and the whole page get loaded in including the sliders:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div_1').load('Page_2');
});
</script>
```

This dont work and the sliders dont show up but the rest of the content does (text):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div_1').load('Page_2 #div_2');
});
</script>
```

Does anybody have a clue what this can depend on?

Comment: Where is `#slider` also do you really have script tags in your js file?

Comment: I dident write out code for the slider and all scripts associated with it, i should have written that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all your script imports on your second page - you only need them to load once - Also each time you load `load_script.js` - it is causing an endless loop since that's where your load function is.  You can then use the callback function of .load() to initialize the slider.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div_that_will_receive_content').load('from_page.html #from_div',function(){
         $( "#slider" ).slider();
    });
});
```

That will break your page 2 if you are also using that page independently though.  If that's the case then you just need to remove the following from page2

```
<script src="load_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Just when I read about 9 word of your post I realised how obvious it was that the script shouldent be inte Page_2 and now I feel like a really beginner at this haha. I just removed the load_script from Page_2 and it worked great.

If you maybe have a minute more you maybe can explain a little simpler what you mean by the callback function?

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Well, the callback function is executed once the load has completed successfully.. So if there are elements that are getting inserted dynamically via the load and you need to manipulate them, you have to wait for them to get inserted in the DOM first.  It is explained pretty good here in the DOCS http://api.jquery.com/load/.. If you just removing the load_script.js from the second page then you don't need to use the callback function, since you already are initializing the slider on dom.ready on page 2

Comment: Ok, think I understand but I will check that document. Thank you once again.